Can a company stall indefinitely on fulfilling warranty obligations?
If a purchased device has an issue covered by its warranty, and the manufacturer/seller is unable to provide a remedy for the issue and refuses to refund the purchase, but claims to be "working on" a solution, is there any point where this becomes a breach of warranty? Or can the company delay warranty obligations indefinitely by stating they are "working on" a solution?
If this would eventually result in the company breaching their obligations, what sort of evidence would be required to prove this in court?
If the company can claim to be working on a solution indefinitely, does any legal mechanism exist for the consumer to compel the company to provide evidence that meaningful work towards a solution is actually being undertaken?
If relevant, I am specifically interested in the answer when the consumer is in Virginia, the manufacturer/seller is in California, and the warranty is the post April 25, 2022 Meta warranty

Your country’s laws state what the company should do. If you can’t convince them to do this then you can persuade them to avoid bad publicity, if that doesn’t work you can only take them to court.

@gnasher729 Sure, but they have continually claimed they are working towards what they're supposed to do (solve the issue), they just haven't actually delivered the result (and I am increasingly doubtful that they ever will). What would it take for me to show in court that they're unable/unwilling to actually deliver the result and just stringing me along (assuming that's what they're doing)?

It doesn't matter if they are "stringing you along". A repair etc. should be done in a certain time, and then you have the right to get your money back - whether that was intentional or not. So you would have to go to court (because only a court can force them to do anything), tell the court when they were informed of the problem, and that it is still not solved. Communication and promises prove that they were aware of the situation.

@gnasher729 Okay, but if neither the warranty documents for the product nor communications about the specific issue include any promises of a specific timeframe of resolution, at what point is that "certain time" reached? Does warranty law in the US (and/or California or Virginia) define an explicit timeframe for resolution? Is there a timeline established in common law or case law? Would it just be up to the judge to pick what seemed "reasonable" to them?

If the issue is a software problem, the warranties are weak to non-existent. Note the clause: "This Warranty does not include any specific guarantees that the Product will be error-free or, regarding uptime or continued availability of data security features of software or online accounts, that any software, firmware or online sites will function uninterrupted or error-free."

@user71659 Yeah, I think whether the specific issue that prompted me to ask this is actually something they have to fix under the warranty is potentially a separate question; for now I'm proceeding on the assumption that it is covered until they assert otherwise, and for the purposes of this question am wondering what the answer is assuming it is an issue covered under the warranty, if only for future reference/academic curiosity
